# JAVA definitions

Tags: java

Скажите пожалуйста,Какая разница между static и non-static members?

Answer (score 1):

[Статические методы и поля](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java#.D0.A1.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.8B_.D0.B8_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8F).

> Статические поля (переменные класса) имеют тот же смысл, что и в C++: каждое такое поле является собственностью класса, поэтому для доступа к статическим полям не требуется создавать экземпляры соответствующего класса.